# MySQL variable through django

Tags: mysql, django

Is there a way to execute MySQL variable commands through [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) such as:

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'
```

or

```
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=2147483
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should [execute custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

```
from django.db import connection
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'")
print cursor.fetchone()
cursor.execute("SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=12345")
cursor.execute("SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_timeout'")
print cursor.fetchone()
```

produced:

```
C:\dev>set_var.py
(u'wait_timeout', u'2147483')
(u'wait_timeout', u'12345')
```

Comment: Can it be executed before making database calls with ORM?